# How to make Java tabbed panes display tabs from right to left?

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

In C#, to make the tabs go from right to left, I set RightToLeft to Yes and RightToLeftFormat to true. How do I do the same thing in Java? How do I set a JTabbedPane's tabs to display from right to left? Please see the image link below to see what I mean by displaying tabs right to left.

http://lh4.ggpht.com/_1bcR6vegNNc/TPDRekNVqWI/AAAAAAAAAB8/TwCqgajEuoI/s640/AdminDashboard.jpg

Comment: setComponentOrientation() works for everybody else. If it doesn't work for you then post your SSCCE (http://sscce.org) demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I assume by "tabbed pane" you are referring to **javax.swing.JTabbedPane**.
To answer your question: *AFAIK* there is no easy way to do what you want. The **BasicTabbedPaneUI**(or the TabbedPaneUI which is defined by your application look and feel) which is responsible for painting the tab area of the tabbed pane would require some changes to be able to do what you need.
If you do not have the time to write your own UI, you could look for solutions in the web. I doubt that there would be a ready to use solution to your question though, but then again, who knows?
Hope this helps you a bit.

Comment: why not use `setComponentOrientation`?

Comment: I tried jTabbedPane.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT); but it doesn't seem to work :(

Comment: maybe called in the wrong Thread or another setting/property interfering... worked for all Look&Feels installed on my laptop (Metal, Nimbus, Motif, Windows, Classic)

Answer (score 1):

Then i'm refer from "How to Use Tabbed Panes" to create a new project based by JTabbedPane component...

It's enough to use "setComponentOrientation" method to change orentation of JTabbedPane.

[link text](http://www.tommyalf.com/2010/11/java-jtabbedpane-orentation.html)

Comment: `tabbedPane.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);` to be exact